# Apache 2.4 AH01695 [LDAP: ldap initialization failed][Unknown (private extension) error]

Tags: apache, active-directory, ldap, rhel7

We are upgrading from Apache 2.2 on RHEL5 to Apache 2.4.12 on RHEL7.  I have added the LDAP configuration similar to before and I am prompted as expected for userid and password,  but Apache is failing to logon and displays the following error in the log:

**error_log**    [Thu Jul 02 16:28:08.277247 2015] [authnz_ldap:info] [pid 18923:tid 140442658866944] [client <>:53830] AH01695: auth_ldap authenticate: user <> authentication failed; URI /mytest/ [LDAP: ldap initialization failed][Unknown (private extension) error]

Is this a configuration directive or missing library issue?  I am able to query the active directory using the ldapsearch from the server.

I have included the LocationMatch, Modules Loaded, and Configure options below:

**Configuration for Location is:**

```
<LocationMatch "/mytest">
    LogLevel debug
    AuthName "My Test Site"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ActiveDirectoryURL"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ServiceAccount"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "ServicePassword"
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

**Related Modules Loaded are:**

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
```

**Configure directives were:**

```
configure --prefix=/u01/httpd  --enable-ssl --enable-unique-id --enable-headers --enable-mime-magic --enable-authnz-ldap=shared --enable-ldap=shared --enable-rewrite --enable-substitute --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-ajp --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-proxy-connect --enable-proxy-http --enable-vhost-alias --enable-speling
```

Answer (score 1):

Must have the rpm apr-util-ldap added in order for LDAP queries to function in addition to other apr/apr-util libraries.

Comment: Is there a way to check whether the apr-util libs are correctly added? Particularly on a Solaris system.